Kinesis stream throughput
I don't understand why AWS kinesis in provisioned mode has really low throughput.
Documentation Ref
Each shard can support up to 1 MB/sec or 1,000 records/sec write throughput or up to 2 MB/sec or 2,000 records/sec read throughput

While on other hand if you see GCP PubSub quotas, their loweset (for smaller region) is also 200MB/s for publisher and 400MB/s for consumer.
Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas
I understand there would be difference in pricing but still 1MB/s for provisioned seems too low to me, even on demand max is 200MB/s.
It seems I'm missing something very basic? Comparing wrong technologies?

The reason the numbers don't seem aligned is that you are comparing the throughput of different entities. The Kinesis throughput of 1MB/s write or 2MB/s read is per shard. Kinesis has no limit on the number of shards per stream. On the other hand, Cloud Pub/Sub has no notion of shard and so the throughput numbers are per topic (the equivalent of stream, not shard). Therefore, the 200MB/s publish and 400MB/s subscribe on Cloud Pub/Sub would be equivalent to a Kinesis stream that has 200 shards, each with 1MB/s write or 2MB/s read.

But isn't ordering in AWS kinesis per shard? and in pubsub it is per topic?

Another thing 1MB/s or 2MB/s still feels insanely low even when one machine, is it not so?

Pub/Sub does not have total ordering per topic, no. If using ordering, then order is guaranteed per key, which is limited to 1MB/s of publish, though has no limit on the subscribe side. Don't conflate "shard" with "machine." These two concepts are not necessarily equivalent.

But @Kamal does that mean you can't get ordering among messages when you have more than 1MB/s of publish rate? You need to take care of that at application end?

Correct, ordering in these systems is relative fine-grained with 1MB/s publish per key/shard, but no limit on the number of keys or shards.
